# Android HTTPClient.execute stopped working after years

Tags: android, apache, mobile, httpclient

I have some Android applications that have not been touched in years.  All of the sudden today they all stopped working.  They all read data from a txt file that sits on an https:// site.

If I change the https:// call to http:// everything works fine again.  I need the https:// for security.  Can anyone tell me what happened?

Keep in mind that this application is a few years old. Did something change in an online library or something to break the https:// calls?

Here is the code.  params[0] hold the website address. I have verified the address is correct. Just changing it to http:// fixes everything. II also know it is not the ssl certificate since I have verified it is all working.

It fails on the httpClient.execute command:

```
protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response;

            List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

                HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

                BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

                InputStream is = buf.getContent();

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;

                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    data.add(line);
                }

                return data;
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

I don't have any logcat or console output that specifies what the error actually is.  I could not find anything.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html refer this site

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before I posted the question. It did not seem to work.  It looks simple but it also failed. Any other ideas?  I'll try that one again as well.

Comment: try to set the header     httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); as like this

Comment: http://blog.dev001.net/post/67082904181/android-using-sni-and-tlsv1-2-with-apache